# How do I extract the value a script assigns to an environment variable, from outside the script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables, text-processing

I have two .sh files (say `test1.sh` and `test2.sh`).

`test1.sh` contains:

```bash
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
```

`test2.sh` contains:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

Both files contain many other shell commands as well.

Now I'm making another .sh file where I want to find the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` values used in the two aforementioned .sh files (`test1.sh` andd `test2.sh`). How to do that?

Comment: Do you know at the start that they are `test1.sh` and `test2.sh`? I *think* you do, but [George's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/940141) supposes not. Can a file have multiple `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=` lines? If so, what should happen? Should the last one be used? Need we worry about code that (re)assigns the variable *after* the `export` command (that would change the exported variable even if `export` isn't used again) or that may not run because it's in a comment or the script tests some condition and runs it just some of the time? You can **[edit]** your question to give this information.

Answer (score 3):

#### You can use a single `grep` command for this.

This extracts the ***`N`*** from lines like `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=N` and prints them one per line, where ***`N`*** is a sequence of one or more decimal digits (0-9):

```bash
grep -hoP '^export OMP_NUM_THREADS=\K\d+' test1.sh test2.sh
```

This prints:

```
8
4
```

#### Caveats

You may notice this is somewhat similar to [wjandrea's way](https://askubuntu.com/a/940163/22949). Like that solution, this will work provided that:

- You know that the files are called `test1.sh` and `test2.sh` (or whatever their names actually are), so you can list the filenames in the command.
- You either don't have to worry about the possibility of multiple matches per file, or you want them all.
- It is acceptable that text to the right of the final digit is ignored, even if there is no space. This probably isn't a problem; presumably you have some control over these scripts (or someone you trust does) and they are not going to give non-numeric values to `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. However, one reasonable alternative is to use `\b` after `\d+` to ensure the match appears on a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (and not produce a result if it doesn't).

And like any solution that does not perform *very* sophisticated analysis (which is [only sometimes possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)), this assumes that:

- You *really* are looking for that particular text; you do not need to actually parse the script and figure out how it will behave when it runs. If your goal is to find out what value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` the script exports to its environment, this may or may not achieve that. It depends how the script is written. In particular, just because a line that matches the pattern appears in a script doesn't ensure the line is executed. The script that contains it [could exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_(command)) first; it could be controlled by [`if`, `case`, or `while`/`until`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Control_flow); it could even be part of a larger command [or comment](https://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_02_02.html#sect_02_02_02) if the preceding line [ends with `\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871332/how-to-tell-bash-that-the-line-continues-on-the-next-line). (This is not an exhaustive list.)
- Note also that if a variable is exported, then later assigned *without* the `export` builtin, the new value becomes the exported value as well. `export` exports a variable and optionally assigns it, but really these are separate things--when you change the value, that applies to the exported variable. Similarly, it is possible for a script to remove variables from the environment after exporting them. (See [this post by Nathan Long](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28331/11938) for details.)

#### What the command-line options `-hoP` do:

- The `-h` flag keeps `grep` from printing the filename; without it, you get:

  ```
  test1.sh:8
  test2.sh:4
  ```
- The `-o` flag prints only the matching text; without it you get the whole line:

  ```
  export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
  export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
  ```
- The `-P` flag uses [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (PCRE). I use that regex dialect because it [supports `\K`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex) (see below).

#### What each part of the pattern `^export OMP_NUM_THREADS=\K\d+` does:

- `^` matches [the beginning of the line](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Remove it if you want `export` to be able to appear anywhere on the line.
- `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=` matches itself literally.
- `\K` [discards the text that has been matched so far](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), so that it will not appear in the match.
- `\d+` matches [any decimal digit](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) (`\d`) [one or more times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (`+`). They don't have to be the same digit.

#### Extracting both values separately, in a third script.

You mentioned you plan to write a third script that uses these values. How best to do that cannot be fully answered, based on what you have asked so far. However, it is common to want to capture separate values into separate shell variables.

You can extract the value from `test1.sh` into the shell variable `n1` and the value from `test2.sh` into the shell variable `n2` like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

get_num_threads() {
    grep -oP '^export OMP_NUM_THREADS=\K\d+' "$1"
}

n1="$(get_num_threads test1.sh)"
n2="$(get_num_threads test2.sh)"
```

This uses [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) to obtain the output of `grep` that would otherwise be [written to stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29). Rather than writing the `grep` command twice or introducing a second step to process *its* output, I put it in a [shell function](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Writing_functions). The function is called twice to assign `n1` and `n2`; `"$1"` [expands to](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Pass_arguments_into_a_function) `test1.sh` in the first call and `test2.sh` in the second.

You would put whatever code you want the script to run, that uses the values stored in `n1` and `n2`, after the code shown above.

- I left off the `-h` flag since, in this script, the `get_num_threads` shell function (which you can call [pretty much whatever you like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115066/1038860)) is only being used to process one file at a time. You can keep the `-h` if you like, though.
- If you want the script to run with a [different shell than `sh`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), change the `#!/bin/sh` [hashbang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) accordingly. If you just plan [to source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell) the script (`. scriptname`), you can remove it entirely; remember that whatever shell sources the script will get `get_num_threads`, `n1`, and `n2` defined unless you subsequently undefine them.
- As written, the script happily assigns multiple numbers to `n1` or `n2` if multiple matching lines exist in `test1.sh` or `test2.sh`, respectively. If this isn't what you want then you'll have to modify the script accordingly.

To illustrate the current behavior for multiple matching lines in the same file, considered what happens if you append the following [`printf` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) to the script so it prints each match surrounded by `[` `]` and separated by a blank line:

```bash
printf '[%s]\n\n' "$n1" "$n2"
```

Suppose `test1.sh` has one match (8) and `test2.sh` has two matches (4 and 5). Then you get:

```
[8]

[4
5]
```

This is to say that `n2` contains both 4 and 5, separated by a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), just as `grep` outputs them.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP '(?<=^export OMP_NUM_THREADS=)[0-9]+' test1.sh test2.sh
```

**Explanation**:

- `grep -o` print only the matching portion of the line
- `grep -P` use Perl-compatible regex
- `(?<=...)` don't consider `...` as part of the match. This is positive lookbehind.
- `^` represents the start of the line, in this context
- `[0-9]+` match one or more digits

Comment: The command in [Eliah's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/940186/301745) is like a better version of mine.

Answer (score 0):

If both are in same folder called `find`:

```
grep -R  -i "OMP_NUM_THREADS=[0-9]*" find/ | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

A simpler version:

```
grep -R  -i "OMP_NUM_THREADS=[0-9]*" find/ | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Sample files:

```
test1.sh --> export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8, export OMP_NUM_THREADS=20
test2.sh --> export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
```

Output:

```
8
20
8
```

Explanation:

1. `grep` recursively goes through the folder with the target files and finds entries with `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and have a set of digits at the end after `=` character.
2. `grep` passes its results to cut which separates them based on the `:` (introduced by `grep`)and takes the second field value.
3. `cut` then passes to another `cut` command or a `sed` command. If `cut` is given the result it repeats what the previous `cut` command did but this time separates the values based on the `=` character. If passed to `sed` it searches and removes non-digits and returns the results.